# How do you send email data with Stripe connect onboarding in test mode?

Tags: stripe-payments, webhooks, payment-gateway, payment

I'm currently setting up Stripe connect on my website and I want to test a webhook that needs the email data to be sent to it. But, in test mode, Stripe says "email is not needed in test mode" and blocks the input. Is there a solution or workaround for this so I can test sending email data?

[image]

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test mode it's not possible to set the email for an Express account during the onboarding flow. But when creating the account with the API, you could set the [`email`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create#create_account-email) parameter (this field is only used to make the account easier to identify for you).

Also note that Stripe don't send any emails in test mode.

Comment: Thank you, solved! I used the API and it worked :)